# CircleAvatar with IconButton not centered

Tags: flutter

I want to center the button in the CircleAvatar, but for smaller radius, it doesn't seem to be centering correctly.

```
                 CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                    radius: 16,
                    child: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        onPressed: () {

                          }
                        }),
                  ),
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The IconButton has some default padding, fix the issue by removing the default padding.
Check the code below, it works perfectly.

```
CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          radius: 16,
          child: IconButton(
            // remove default padding here
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            color: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ),
```

Output of the code:
[image]

Comment: If you try this on an Ipad with a larger Avatar and icons size it is no longer centred

Answer (score 1):

You can use floatingActionButton to achieve that

```
Container(
  child: floatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
  ),
),
```

Hope it helps..!

Answer (score 0):

`CircleAvatar` generally we used for displaying image, we can have some better option like material button

```
   MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              color: Colors.blue,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              child: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                size: 16,
              ),
              shape: CircleBorder(),
            )
```

**Output:**

[image]